# Google text-to-speech nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, text-to-speech

I am trying to code a nodejs application that uses [google tts api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-tts-api) what my problem is, it returns an url to an audio. I need to be able to hear the text automatically without going to link and playing the audio.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you're looking for and what you've tried so far to get it.  This isn't enough for anyone to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, install mpv player then try this ==>

```
const googleTTS = require("google-tts-api");
let mpv = require('node-mpv');
let mpvPlayer = new mpv();
googleTTS("Hello world", "en",1).then(url => mpvPlayer.load(url));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the url and "play it" – it's a link to audio file. Example using [`play-sound`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound):

```
const googleTTS = require("google-tts-api");
const player = require("play-sound")();

googleTTS("Hello World", "en", 1).then(url => player.play(url));
```

The `play-sound` package works by executing an external player – see [#options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound#options) for a list. You can even specify another one with the `player` option. The player needs to support playing from https urls, obviously. I tried it with [mpv](https://mpv.io/) and it works perfectly.

If you can't or don't want to use the external player, you'll need to fetch the audio, get the data buffer from response and play it somehow. So something along this way:

```
googleTTS("Hello World", "en", 1).then(url => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.buffer())
    .then(buffer => playWithSomething(buffer));
});
```

Comment: I tried using your play sound code but i doesn't play the audio at the url and it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: It did that to me when it couldn't find any of the listed players. What OS are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I am using node 7.5.0 and npm 4.1.2

Comment: And do you have any of the listed players installed? Please try running `which mplayer afplay mpg123 mpg321 play omxplayer ` in terminal (and post the output here).

Comment: when i use Afplay, mplayer , mpg123, play, omxplayer, i get this error:

`===> (node:7148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: player.play is not a function
(node:7148) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: How do you import/require the `player` package?

Answer (score 0):

### Play directly to speakers in nodejs

#### Install

1. [Terminal] install play: `sudo apt install sox`
2. [Terminal] install encoder: `sudo apt install libsox-fmt-mp3`
3. [Terminal] install `node-gtts`: `npm install node-gtts`
4. [IDE][speech.js] See code listing

```js
const gtts = require('node-gtts')('en');
const {exec} = require("child_process");

function speak(text) {
    var mp3FileName = `/home/toddmo/${text}.mp3`
    gtts.save(mp3FileName, text)
    exec(`play '${mp3FileName}'`)
}
```

#### Notes

- it would be better all in memory but the mp3 encoder lame is currently not installing on the current version of nodejs

If they get that fixed, then this code will work

```js
var lame = require('lame');
const Speaker = require('speaker');

// Create the Speaker instance
const speaker = new Speaker({
  channels: 2,          // 2 channels
  bitDepth: 16,         // 16-bit samples
  sampleRate:44100,     // 44,100 Hz sample rate
  device: 'hw:2,0'
});

// create the Encoder instance
var encoder = new lame.Encoder({
  // input
  channels: 2,        // 2 channels (left and right)
  bitDepth: 16,       // 16-bit samples
  sampleRate: 44100,  // 44,100 Hz sample rate

  // output
  bitRate: 128,
  outSampleRate: 22050,
  mode: lame.STEREO // STEREO (default), JOINTSTEREO, DUALCHANNEL or MONO
});

// raw PCM data from stdin gets piped into the encoder
// the generated MP3 file gets piped to speaker                
gtts.stream(text).pipe(encoder).pipe(speaker);
```